# Have trouble implement the variable loop in haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-email

I use *ruby on rails* to get some variables and suppose to send them in email format to some email address.

```
%div
- @msg.each do |line|
    %p = "#{line}"
    %br
```

The msg is the string array I passed in and would like to get each element in separate line. How can I achieve that. The above code won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the key things of coding HAML is you really are only going to have one item per line, plus you automatically get a div tag as the default tag.  So you might as well add a class to your div to differentiate it.  Additionally, make sure your indentation is correct:

```
.messages
  - @msg.each do |line|
    %p= line
```

You don't really need a br because the p will break for you, and following a tag with '=' will automatically give you the interpolation.